# custom post type not showing in menu

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, functions, menus

I have created a simple plugin to manage my portfolio as a custom post type. everything is OK and works great, but there is no ability to add my custom post type to the menu(also for its taxonomies).
note: I have checked as many as ways that I knew before. (show_ui, show_in_nav_menus,...)
below is my codes for my CPT

```
<?php
function oseo_custom_post_type() {
    register_taxonomy( 'portfolio_cat', array('oseo_portfolio'),
        array(
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'label'             => __('Portfolio Filters', 'oseo-portfolio'),
            'singular_label'    => __('portfolio Filter', 'oseo-portfolio'),
            'rewrite'           => array('slug' =>  'portfolio_type')
        )
    );
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Portfolios', 'Post Type General Name', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Portfolio', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Portfolios', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Portfolio', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Portfolios', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Portfolio', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Portfolio', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Portfolio', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Portfolio', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Portfolio', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
    );
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Portfolios', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Portfolios', 'oseo-portfolio' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'custom-fields', ),
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'portfolio_cat' ),
        'hierarchical'        => true,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'   =>  array('slug'    =>  'portfolio'),
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    flush_rewrite_rules();

    register_post_type( 'oseo_portfolio', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'oseo_custom_post_type');
?>
```

one other thing I think may cause this problem is that I use metaboxes for this CPT. I can post those if needed.

Comment: I found this issue was due to caching on my local browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// portfolio code
function codenovo_portfolio_init(){
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Portfolio', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Portfolio', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'portfolio'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio'),
        'new_item' => __('New Portfolio'),
        'view_item' => __('View Portfolio'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No portfolio found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No portfolio found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Portfolio'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => false,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug'       => 'portfolio',
            'with_front' => FALSE,
        )
    );
    register_post_type('portfolio',$args);

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Portfolio Category', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Types' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Category' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ),
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Category Name' ),
    );


    register_taxonomy('portfoliocategory',array('portfolio'), array(
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'portifolio_category' ),
    ));


}
add_action('init', 'codenovo_portfolio_init');
```

Comment: thank you for your post, you need to explain your answer.

Comment: I have just missed some spelling checks